# Unable to access S3 bucket image from angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I’m trying to access S3 bucket image from angular application but it’s giving 403 ( forbidden error ) but they are public and can be accessible directly.
[image]

Is there any CORS issue because of angular ? Because in Aws images are public and I’m able to look into them if access them directly

Comment: what are the bucket policies?

Answer (score 0):

Can you load image directly in browser accessing via url? like /image.jpg

if yes there may be a CORS rule, which you need to set in s3 bucket
you can read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html

but for viewing only you can try to assign:

```
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
```

Comment: Yes , I’m able to access it directly via url